# Django-Javascript - materialcss breaks javascript code when adding new elements to the body of html template

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

Well this is making my head spin... When I run the following code in a test environment without material css loaded, I get the expected output, a dropdown menu with animals to select from. However, if I run this exact same code with material css loaded, it just displays the title and no dropdown is visible. Why does this happen?

html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load materializecss %}
{% block content %}
    <button id  = 'id_graph_type'>Add Stuff</button>
{% endblock %}
```

javascript

```
graphInput.addEventListener('click', e=>{
    var values = ["dog", "cat", "parrot", "rabbit"];
 
    var select = document.createElement("select");
    select.name = "pets";
    select.id = "pets"
   
    for (const val of values) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = val;
      option.text = val.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + val.slice(1);
      select.appendChild(option);
    }
   
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    label.innerHTML = "Choose your pets: "
    label.htmlFor = "pets";
   
    document.body.appendChild(label).appendChild(select);
})
```

Comment: If you examine the dom in developer tools, is the dropdown present and invisible or not present at all?
Check if the expected classes are there?

Comment: Yeah when I pull up developer tools the HTML is there, but when I click on <select> for the dropdown and go to style, it has a property display: none. Could this be causing my problem?

Comment: That is A problem. Not sure WHY its giving display: none, but that will cause it to not appear.  You have 2 options... make it stop giving display none. Or use JS after it loads to change it to display: block.

Comment: If its working fine without materializecss, then obviously materialize is giving it the display :none property. Try find out why. Alternatively, just set it to display:block with JS.